# Making complex Terraform output optional?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an unenviable situation where I have to pass some unnecessary information into a module to make one thing (a Private Hosted R53 Zone), but not a bunch of others.

tl;dr, I'm trying to suppress outputs. If I didn't need to expose this output, my plan would behave as I expect. Outputs that produce strings or tuples were fine with me using the same condition to decide whether or not they would be evaluated, but the one below is still evaluating the attributes of the object:

```
output endpoint_dns_entries {
value = contains(local.de_dupe_phz_names, var.service["phz_name"]) ? {empty = [""]
emptyalso = [""]} : {
dns_names = aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.*.dns_entry[*].dns_name
hosted_zone_ids = aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.*.dns_entry[*].hosted_zone_id
}
}
```

yields errors:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

on ../../endpoint-with-phz/outputs.tf line 12, in output "endpoint_dns_entries":

12: dns_names = aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.*.dns_entry[*].dns_name

This value does not have any attributes.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on ../../endpoint-with-phz/outputs.tf line 13, in output "endpoint_dns_entries":

13: hosted_zone_ids = aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.*.dns_entry[*].hosted_zone_id

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Any ideas on how to make this output optional?

Comment: If you were to output only the `dns_entry` part, would that be a list or a map? Have you tried without the wildcard?

Comment: Ah, ok, it's a list of maps it seems. How was the VPC Endpoint resource created, as a list?

Comment: Without the wildcard did work in the end, it was previously a list in the module, but I had moved the iterable to the impl level and this was the last hold-over! aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.0.dns_entry[*].hosted_zone_id is valid